# Why does SAT-UNSAT $\in NP \implies NP = coNP$

Tags: np-complete, np, complexity-classes, co-np

I was reading [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76594/126008) about the DP completeness of the problem SAT-UNSAT (both are well defined in this post). The [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/76612/126008) added a note at the end that states the class complexity DP differs from NP, unless NP = coNP.

I fail to see why.

I searched and I came across multiples posts such at [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/114959/reducing-from-npc-to-co-npc-np-co-np) and [that one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75631/how-do-i-prove-that-sat-in-conp-implies-np-conp) that prove that if SAT-UNSAT is in coNP, then NP = coNP. But unless the fact that SAT-UNSAT $\in NP \implies$ SAT-UNSAT $\in coNP$ (which I do not see), then those proofs are not exactly what would help me. The same goes for [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69446/126008), I would need SAT-UNSAT $\in coNP$.

***Question*** : Considering the first question (and the answer associated), if the problem SAT-UNSAT $\in NP$, why does NP = coNP.

My take :
Well, I can see that the problem SAT-UNSAT is NP-hard and coNP-hard. If SAT-UNSAT $\in NP$, then SAT-UNSAT is NP-complete. This implies things such that the problem UNSAT (which is coNP-complete) is NP-hard since we can reduce UNSAT to SAT-UNSAT which is NP-complete. That's all I got and that doesn't really help.

I'd appreciate any clarification on the subject. Thanks to you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a coNP problem which is NP-hard.

Let $A$ be any problem in NP. Since $X$ is NP-hard, there is a polytime reduction from $A$ to $X$. Since $X$ is in coNP, this shows that $A$ is in coNP.

We have shown that $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{coNP}$. Now suppose $B$ is in coNP. Then $\overline{B}$ is in NP, and so in coNP. Hence $B$ is in NP. This shows that also $\mathsf{coNP} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$, and so $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{coNP}$.

Comment: Are you implying that if a problem DP is in NP, then is also is in coNP? Because my question is about SAT-UNSAT (or any DP-complete problem really), and nowhere does it say that it is in coNP.

Comment: Let's suppose that a DP-complete problem is in NP, then why is it that the problem is in coNP?

Comment: Switch NP and coNP on my answer everywhere.

Comment: Well, I could have figured this out on my own really... All this post wasn't really needed after all